# Why do these sql queries take so long to execute

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization

I have a table called `holdings_all` which has over 65m rows, every day new rows gets inserted on it, one of the columns is `trade_type`, its value will depend on the comparison of the value of
`SharesOwned` between `DateAdded-Fund-Ticker` of today and previous day of `DateAdded-Fund-Ticker`, possible values will be:

- If `SharesOwned` of today is equal to `SharesOwned` of previous day then
  `Trade_Type` = 0.
- If `SharesOwned` of today is smaller than `SharesOwned` of previous day then
  `Trade_Type` = 1.
- If `SharesOwned` of today is larger than `SharesOwned` of previous day then
  `Trade_Type` = 2.
- If `SharesOwned` of today doesn't exist in previous day then
  `Trade_Type` = 3.
- If `SharesOwned` of today doesn't exist but previous day exist then
  `Trade_Type` = 4.

To make thinks faster and avoid rows corruption then I took this approach:

- Download new rows in a table called `tmp_holdings_all`.
- Get previous day rows from `holdings_all` in a table called `mlha`.
- Finally, make any queries in `tmp_holdings_all` and after that move it to `holdings_all` table.

For the type 0, 1, and 2 I get the rows affected and correct in few seconds, but when it comes to type 3 and 4 it takes so long even more than hours and never finish, what am I doing wrong here?

```
UPDATE tmp_holdings_all uha
    JOIN (SELECT tha.id as cid, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN mlha.SharesOwned = tha.SharesOwned then 0
                    WHEN mlha.SharesOwned > tha.SharesOwned then 1
                    WHEN mlha.SharesOwned < tha.SharesOwned then 2
                END AS CTrade_type
            FROM mlha
            JOIN tmp_holdings_all tha
            ON tha.fund = mlha.fund 
            AND tha.ticker = mlha.ticker) ttha
    ON uha.id = ttha.cid
    SET uha.Trade_type = ttha.CTrade_type;
```

Trade_type 3 and 4:

```
UPDATE tmp_holdings_all uha
    JOIN (SELECT 
                ha.id as cid,
                CASE 
                    WHEN mlha.id IS NULL then 3
                END AS CTrade_type
            FROM mlha
                RIGHT JOIN tmp_holdings_all ha
                ON ha.fund = mlha.fund 
                AND ha.ticker = mlha.ticker
                where mlha.id IS NULL) ttha
    ON uha.id = ttha.cid
    SET 
        uha.Trade_type = ttha.CTrade_type;
    
REPLACE INTO tmp_holdings_all(Fund,ticker,SharesOwned, Trade_Type)
    SELECT 
        mlha.Fund, mlha.ticker, mlha.SharesOwned, 
        CASE 
            WHEN ha.id IS NULL then 4
        END AS Trade_type
    FROM mlha
        LEFT JOIN tmp_holdings_all ha
        ON ha.fund = mlha.fund 
        AND ha.ticker = mlha.ticker
        WHERE ha.id IS NULL
```

`holding_all` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_holdings_all` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DateAdded` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `Fund` char(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `Asset` char(96) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `rank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Weighting` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `Ticker` char(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `Style` char(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `FirstBought` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `SharesOwned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Sector` char(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `Price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `Country` char(25) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `Currency` char(3) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `PriceUSD` decimal(13,6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `Trade_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are unique, get rid of `id` and add this to `mlha` and `ha`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(fund, ticker)
```

If not `mlha` may need `INDEX(ticker, fund)`

Is a "fund" composed of many "tickers"?

I assume that `tmp_holdings_all` is *much* smaller than `holdings_all`?  In that case, indexes in `tha` are probably not important; instead, it should be controlling the lookups into the big table for updating.  The trick is to make sure it can do it with a lookup instead of a table scan.

Use `VARCHAR`, not `CHAR` unless the column is truly fixed-length.

What is in `tmp_holdings_all`?  Updates for existing holdings?  Or new holdings?  Or Both (eg `country`)??  The answer to this may lead to doing multiple queries instead of one.  Or it may lead to using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  (`REPLACE` is passé, and assigns a new `id`.)

Will you be updating all 65M rows?  If so, I would expect it to take hours or days.  At that point, I would recommend doing the task in chunks:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

`holdings_all` does *not* contain a daily history, correct?  You are really tracking 65M tickers.  (That sounds unrealistic, so I am trying to understand what a "holding" is.  Maybe "Puts", etc are included?)

Comment: **Is a "fund" composed of many "tickers"?** Yes, it may have many.
I use `tmp_holdings_all` to inert new data and update it when I am doing the join with `mlha`, it will be faster, after that I move the rows to 'holdings_all`.
** The trick is to make sure it can do it with a lookup instead of a table scan**
Can you explain more?
**Will you be updating all 65M rows?** No, just the new rows that has been downloaded and inserted in `tmp_holdings_all`.  
**holdings_all does not contain a daily history, correct?** Correct, I am tracking the daily, so each day I have to repeat the process.

Comment: How many rows in `tmp_holdings_all` when the `UPDATE` is performed?  And in mlha?

Comment: Time each query separately; I suspect that the `REPLACE` is taking longer.

Comment: I added to the first couple of paragraphs.

Comment: `tmp_holdings_all` and `mlha` approximitly 2m rows.

Comment: @HAßdøµ - How many rows in `ttha`?  (Updating a full 2M rows will take a long time.)  Is the slowness interfering with other operations?  If that is the "problem", I can recommend workarounds.  If the "problem" is that it takes a long time to finish, that may not be solvable.  Can you get `EXPLAIN UPDATE...`.

Comment: I have other operations update the same table in lesser time, just few minutes, the server and it's configuration is already optimized for it, only with the queries I mentioned are slow, and yes, I would be open for any workarounds.

Comment: To avoid blocking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: This what is returned from `EXPLAIN`: `id;select_type;table;type;possible_keys;key;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
1;PRIMARY;uha;ALL;PRIMARY;NULL;NULL;NULL;1631313;
1;PRIMARY;<derived2>;ref;key0;key0;8;portfolios.uha.id;1630989;
2;DERIVED;ha;index;NULL;FundTicker_indx;107;NULL;1631313;"Using index"
2;DERIVED;mlha;index;NULL;MaxDate_Fund_indx;80;NULL;1630989;"Using where; Using index; Not exists; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)"
`

Comment: Sorry, I have run out of ideas.